# How to write a test case for this Rails autoload error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a model `Foo` defined in `app/models/foo.rb`:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    # do bar
  end
end
```

This method is called in a use case defined in `app/use_cases/do_bar.rb`

```
module UseCases
  class DoBar
    def call
      Foo.bar
    end
  end
end
```

Recently, I had the following airbrake error:

> undefined method `bar' for UseCases::Foo:Class

I assume that this error would be sorted out by prepending `::` to `Foo` in the use case, but I'm not sure how to force this error?  I have use case tests already and those tests pass with or without the `::`.

**How can I write a test to ensure that prepending `::` to `Foo` is the correct resolution for this error?**

Comment: Do you actually have UseCases::Foo?

Comment: @violarium, that is a reasonable question :P  no, i don't.

Comment: But it's strange, If you don't, you will have an error like "NameError: uninitialized constant UseCases"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to be reproducible whenever class `Foo` is defined down in the module hierarchy of `DoBar` class.

Let's start with a working example:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    p 'bar'
  end
end

module UseCases
  class DoBar
    def call
      Foo.bar
    end
  end
end

UseCases::DoBar.new.call #=> bar
```

We can reproduce `undefined method 'bar'` exception by adding the following class:

```
module UseCases
  class Foo
  end
end
```

While in the same module as `DoBar`, class `UseCases::Foo` takes precedence over `::Foo` class. If we move `UseCases::Foo` more deeper into the hierarchy, our exception will disappear:

```
# having UseCases::OneMore::Foo doesn't cause any problems
module UseCases
  module OneMore
    class Foo
    end
  end
end
```